# CIAO and python

Tags: python, subprocess

I have been trying to incorporate Chandra Analysis tool (ciao) in python http://cxc.harvard.edu/ciao4.4/scripting/runtool.html, with 'wavdetect' being the command in question I use from ciao. While 'wavdetect' works well when I specify the exact name of the input/output files, it does not seem to provide me any output when I use a concatenated name for these files. (I verified that the concatenated files are being read well in wavdetect but the .wait() status is 1). Any pointers as to probable cause (solution?) to this error would be helpful. I paste a part of my program here:

```
from subprocess import *
p=Popen(["wavdetect","image1.img",
"deep_source_list.fits","deep_scell.fits",
"deep_img.img", "deep_bkg.bkg",     
"psffile=xrt_psf.fits",
"scales=1,1.41421,2.0,2.8284,4.0","regfile=region.reg",
"sigthresh=1e-6","clobber=yes"], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
p.wait()
```

(WORKS WELL)

---

```
from subprocess import *
for k in (3,4):
innfile="9" + str(k) + ".img"
listfile="9" + str(k) + "_source_list.fits"
scell="9" + str(k) + "_scell.fits"
image="9" + str(k) + "_img.img"
bkg="9" + str(k) + "_bkg.bkg"
regionfile="9" + str(k) + "region.reg"
print(regionfile)
q=Popen(["wavdetect",innfile,listfile,scell,image,bkg,
"psffile=xrt_psf.fits", "scales= 1,1.41421,2.0,2.8284,4.0", regionfile,
"sigthresh=1e-6", "clobber=yes"], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
q.wait()
```

(Gives me q.wait()=1 and no output)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of closure, I am answering my own question:

I wrote to the ciao help desk who suggested me to make the following changes:

```
 innfile="infile=9{}.img".format(k) listfile="outfile=9{}_source_list.fits".format(k) scell="scellfile=9{}_scell.fits".format(k) image="imagefile=9{}_img.img".format(k) bkg="defnbkgfile=9{}_bkg.bkg".format(k) regionfile="regfile=9{}region.reg".format(k)
```

and Viola it worked!